# How to run docker commands in windows using a Java program?

Tags: java, docker, processbuilder

Ref: 
https://rominirani.com/docker-on-windows-mounting-host-directories-d96f3f056a2c

I want to manipulate my data by using docker image of gdal. The problem is I have to create a GUI wrapper in Java using Swing. How can run the docker command from Java ProcessBuilder? That is run the powershell commands from Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a plenty of Java wrappers around Docker API, like [docker-java](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java) or [docker-java-api](https://github.com/amihaiemil/docker-java-api). Pick one and you're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ipconfig", "/all");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pb.start().getInputStream()));
String str = "";
while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Replace "ipconfig", "/all" by your command (ex: "docker", "ps", "--all")